# How to change emacs shell mode color theme

Tags: linux, shell, emacs

[image: screenshot]

Anyone know how to change the color theme in emacs shell mode? I'm using the latest emacs 25.3.1 and in shell mode, I find that the stdout font color always becomes red after a dash (in attached image link). It is really annoying and I don't know what to do with it, I want it be white just like other stdout text. I have "(add-hook 'shell-mode-hook 'ansi-color-for-comint-mode-on)"  in my .emacs, but seems it does not do anything.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: @jww thx man, will find a better place

Comment: The emacs SE site is https://emacs.stackexchange.com. Also, please edit your question and inline the image.